# When filling out an online visa application for UK, how can you apply at a consulate different from your current place of residency?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, applications

I am an Indian passport holder currently residing in Trinidad, Port of Spain. I want to apply for a UK visit visa. I am planning to go India for vacation in February, and would want to apply for UK visit visa while I'm there.

However, when I filled out the application for the visa online, it automatically inserted the location as Trinidad. Since I want it to be India, how can I correct this?

Comment: Why not apply for the visa in Trinidad?  It is more common to apply in your place of residence than in your country of nationality.

Comment: Plus it is probably easier to get it done in Trinidad - fewer lines

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to [fill out a new application](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa) and it's indeed possible to choose to apply in India if your residency is in Trinidad and Tobago. I would therefore simply try again, being careful to select India as your application point in the beginning.